# Rotate a Text view and its frame in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I can rotate the Text in SwiftUI using rotationEffect but it doesn't rotate the frame. As shown in the image, the text is rotated but the frame is still horizontal. I would like to rotate the frame too so it doesn't take up horizontal space. This is for a Mac app where I'm using HStack to prevent the Text and Circle views from overlapping when the window changes size.

[image: vertical text]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Vertical text")
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            Circle()
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
    }
}
```

One suggestion is to use ZStack. This fixes the appearance of the Text view next to the Circle but it doesn't rotate the frame of the Text view. And if ZStack is used with a resizable window then the Circle can overlap the Text view which is why I was trying to use HStack in my original example.

[image: resizable window]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Vertical text")
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            Circle()
                .padding(.leading)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting with iOS 16, Apple has opened up custom layout by introducing the new Layout protocol. Thus, we can actually wrap up this task into a single child custom container, that can compute the total space required after rotation and place the child. This would eliminate the use of @State. And we can fallback to the old solution if we need to support iOS 15 or below. I will add an answer if I have the time to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Applying a fixedSize and frame size to the Text view appears to fix my problem. This also works well for windows that are resizable because the HStack prevents the Text view and Circle view from overlapping.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Vertical text")
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 180)
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 200)
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've saved me a day of headaches!

Answer (score 6):

Using a `fixedSize()` and then an explicit `frame` modifier is the right methodology, but you don't want to have to guess-and-check update your `Text`'s frame every time you change the containing text. We can use a custom view modifier and the preferences system to pass the exact right size up the view hierarchy

[image]

```swift
struct RotatedVertical: ViewModifier {

    /// Whether the view should be rotated so its baseline ends up on the left is `true`, right if `false.`
    let baselineLeft: Bool = false

    /// A binding to a `State` variable that gets assigned to the caller's frame size.
    let frame: Binding<CGSize?>

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(key: TextSizeKey.self, value: proxy.size)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(TextSizeKey.self, perform: { newSize in
            frame.wrappedValue = newSize
        })
        .fixedSize() // Calculate and fix our ideal size before rotation
        .rotationEffect(baselineLeft ? .degrees(90) : .degrees(270))
        .frame(width: frame.wrappedValue?.height, height: frame.wrappedValue?.width) // Assign the flipped sizes via the Preference system updates
    }
}

extension View {

    /// Wrap our `ViewModifier` in a convenience method
    func rotatedVertical(baselineLeft: Bool = false, frame: Binding<CGSize?>) -> some View {
        modifier(RotatedVertical(frame: frame))
    }
}

struct RotatedTextView: View {
    @State var textSize: CGSize?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .rotatedVertical(frame: $textSize)
            .border(.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "TextSizeKey" inside RotatedVertical modifier ?

Comment: Ah sorry for not including that. IIRC it was just a custom `PreferenceKey` struct that had a value of `CGSize?` or `CGSize` with a default value of `.none` or `.zero` respectively

Comment: This is very neat, thank you. I wondered if gestures on the rotated view are also rotated? I assume they are not, though?

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 16 and later, we can harvest the power of the new `Layout` protocol. This solution gets the layout right, performs no state update, and does not require you to write down magic numbrersn

```swift
struct VerticalLabel: View {
    var text: Text

    var body: some View {
        VerticalLayout() {
            text
        }
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
    }

    private struct VerticalLayout: Layout {
        func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
            let size = subviews.first!.sizeThatFits(.unspecified)
            return .init(width: size.height, height: size.width)
        }

        func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
            subviews.first!.place(at: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), anchor: .center, proposal: .unspecified)
        }
    }
}
```

The code defines a `VerticalLayout`, which asks `Text` for its unconstrained size (hence `.unspecified`). It then returns a size by swapping width and height. Lastly, it places the text at the center of the frame.

The `VerticalLabel` view uses this layout to achieve the effect of rotating the frame. After that, it calls `rotationEffect` to complete the rotation visually.

Comment: Long text overflows. How to incorporate some truncation mode?

Answer (score 4):

Building on @nteissler answer to measure the text dynamically I have the following (see comments in code for explanation)

```swift
struct VerticalRotationModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var contentSize = CGSize.zero
    let rotation: VerticalRotationType

    // 1) Transparent overlay captures the view's size using `ContentSizePreferenceKey`
    // 2) Setting a `.preference` triggers `.onPreferenceChange` which sets the @State contentSize
    // 3) The frame size is set based on the @State contentSize with the height and width flipped
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fixedSize()
            .overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear.preference(key: ContentSizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(ContentSizePreferenceKey.self, perform: { newSize in
                contentSize = newSize
            })
            .rotationEffect(rotation.asAngle)
            .frame(width: contentSize.height, height: contentSize.width)
    }

    enum VerticalRotationType {
        case clockwise
        case anticlockwise
        
        var asAngle: Angle {
            switch(self) {
            case .clockwise:
                return .degrees(90)
            case .anticlockwise:
                return .degrees(-90)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private struct ContentSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

        static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
            value = nextValue()
        }
    }
}


struct VerticalRotationModifier_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Vertical text")
                .modifier(VerticalRotationModifier(rotation: .anticlockwise))
                .border(.green)
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very neat and useful solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok, before start making things complicated, let's try to make them simple, how about the following:

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Vertical text")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
        Circle()
            .padding(.leading)
    }
    .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
}
```

yes, it gives not real but only visual effect, however it is fast and simple and very extendable... not enough?

Comment: I should note that this is for a Mac app. If I use ZStack, the Circle will cover up the vertical Text when the window changes to certain sizes. I used HStack in my example to prevent the Text view and Circle view from overlapping.

Comment: I edited my question to convey an issue I have with using the ZStack approach.

Comment: I posted an answer that seems to fix my problem. Let me know what you think.