# How to display vertically an array of turned images in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, foreach, image-rotation

My app has an array `hand` of a struct with a property `let blatt: Image`. During `init`, an `Image` is assigned to this property.

To display such an array horizontally, I use the following code (`scaledWidth` is some constant):

```
HStack(spacing: 10) {
    ForEach((0 ..< hand.count), id: \.self) {
        hand[$0].blatt
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit() 
            .frame(height: scaledWidth)
            .border(.black)
    }
}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

This is what I expected.

Another array is to be displayed vertically. For this, I am using the following code:

```
VStack(spacing: 10) {
    ForEach((0 ..< hand.count), id: \.self) {
        hand[$0].blatt
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit() 
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
            .frame(width: scaledWidth, height: scaledWidth)
            .border(.black)
    }
}
```

This gives additionally the following output:

[image]

Here, the height of each frame, as indicated by the bordered frame, is the height of the unrotated image.

Since I know the aspect ratio `aspectRatioBlatt` of the images, I can adjust the output using `.frame(width: scaledWidth, height: scaledWidth / aspectRatioBlatt)`. Then, the frames have the correct dimensions and the correct spacing, but the images inside are too little. Again, the height of the frame is then equal to the height of the inner unrotated image.

I have tried many view modifiers and multiple combinations, but failed. I even tried to use a custom layout as [suggested here for vertical Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76570744/1987726), but this did not work either.
Of course I could use a 2nd set of turned images, but it should be possible without it in SwiftUI.

How to do it right?

Comment: SwiftUI.Layout might be an option

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. I tries this (see link above), but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simplest to rotate the `HStack` instead.

Otherwise, if you know the aspect ratio then you can set the frame size before rotation and then adjust the height after rotation:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let width = CGFloat(50)
    let aspectRatio = 31.0 / 15.0
    let colors: [Color] = [.green, .blue, .mint, .teal, .purple]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach((0 ..< colors.count), id: \.self) { index in
                    Image(systemName: "figure.wave")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: width, height: width * aspectRatio)
                        .background { colors[index] }
                        .border(.black)
                }
            }
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach((0 ..< colors.count), id: \.self) { index in
                    Image(systemName: "figure.wave")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: width, height: width * aspectRatio)
                        .background { colors[index] }
                        .border(.black)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                        .frame(height: width)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: RotatedImages]

I found it also worked by setting only the width and then using `scaledToFill`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let width = CGFloat(50)
    let colors: [Color] = [.green, .blue, .mint, .teal, .purple]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach((0 ..< colors.count), id: \.self) { index in
                    Image(systemName: "figure.wave")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: width)
                        .background { colors[index] }
                        .border(.black)
                }
            }
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach((0 ..< colors.count), id: \.self) { index in
                    Image(systemName: "figure.wave")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: width)
                        .background { colors[index] }
                        .border(.black)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                        .frame(height: width)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Rotating the `HStack`is indeed the easiest way. I did not think about it. The problem, however, is that rotation is about an anchor point, normally the center. This means that the distance to the border depends on the length of the `HStack`. I tried to get this distance using a `GeometryReader`, but failed. But the other suggested methods do work well.